# JSON response at ajax request to JS variables

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, response

I am trying to upload files with dynamic names and get those dynamic names back.

In detail, I have 2 page `form.php` and `upload.php`. When upload button is pressed on `form.php` then request sent to `upload.php`, where 2 files (DLpath and PhotoIDPath) are uploaded to server with dynamically names e.g :

**DLpath=documents/20161130232311i8hGn0HzJT276415832.png**

And

**PhotoIDPath=documents/20161130232311SSRqCyIbKKalock.png**.

It is working fine. Then on `upload.php`, I am encoding those file names as JSON array **i.e.**

```
$response  = array ('DLpath'=>$Dlpath ,'PhotoIDPath'=>$PhotoIDPath);
echo json_encode($response);
```

And firebug snapshot is :

[image]

I want to get DLpath in `var jsDlpath` and PhotoIDPath in `var jsPhotoIDPath`

And my code ( Not working) to get response is :

```
complete: function(response) 
    {
    var jsDlpath=response.DLpath;
    var jsPhotoIDPath=response.PhotoIDPath;
alert(jsDlpath+" - "+jsPhotoIDPath)
}
```

And alert show :

> undefined - undefine

If you can help me to gwt those values in js variables, I will be very thankful to you.

Comment: have you parsed the `response`? .. try loging the `response` and if it's a string.. use `JSON.parse` to parse it to `json object`

Comment: What are you receiving in `response`? Can you post here?

Comment: I think you should do it in success no complete

Comment: `console.log(response)` shows what?

Comment: When I tried : var obj=JSON.parse(response);
It gives error "SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 2 of the JSON data"

AND $("#returned").html(response.responseText); is giving {"DLpath":"documents\/20161201000303tHD2cxzz0u276415832.png","PhotoIDPath":"documents\/20161201000303ZGeDG1odOEalock.png"}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're encoding you `response` in server side you should parse it in the js side, you could use **[`$.parsejson()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsejson/)** :

```
success: function(response) 
{
    var response = $.parseJson(response);
     //if $.parseJson dont work, use JSON.parse

    var jsDlpath=response.DLpath;
    var jsPhotoIDPath=response.PhotoIDPath;

    alert(jsDlpath+" - "+jsPhotoIDPath)
}
```

**NOTE :** Use `success/done` callback instead of complete.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If running in pure javascript you will find that there are two response attributes: responseText and responseXML.  You probably want:

```
var data = JSON.parse(response.responseText);
```

A complete example, using curl from https://gist.github.com/bitdivine/7ddd943387a4350336dd (but jquery will do fine as well) to get open issues on Github:

```
curl('https://api.github.com/repos/gchq/CyberChef/issues?state=open')
.then((res) => JSON.parse(res.responseText))
.then((data) => console.log(data))
```